# What does #[...] mean in emacs-lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I am puzzled by the expression

```
#[nil "\300\207"
      [nil]
      1]
```

as a value of `skeleton-pair-filter-function`.

Is this an alternative way of writing function in elisp? Or lisp in general?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a byte code function object, the result of byte compiling a function.

See manual entry [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Byte_002dCode-Objects)